# Redux flow data to send details to action via user

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a **React/Redux** (Using Typescript) application where I'm getting a list of users from the server side. Problem comes when I try to request the list of users again when the users try to filter by an input text I have added. The action never get the data(user filter) from the user so I get the list of users not filtered as at the beginning.

**Action**

```
export const getUsers = (data?: UserFiltersState) => {
    const url = encodeQueryData(data)
    return {
        type: UserActionTypes.GET_USERS,
        payload: fetch('app/admin/user/search/multisearch' + url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => json)
        .catch(ex => {
            console.log('users request error.', ex)
            return []
        })
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
export const reducer: Reducer<UsersState> = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UserActionTypes.GET_USERS: {
            return  {...state, loading: true, data: action.payload }
        }
        default: {
            return state
        }
    }
}
export { reducer as usersReducer }
```

**userlistcomponent**

```
class AdminUsersPage extends Component<AllProps, AdminUserPageState> {
    constructor(props: AllProps) {
        super(props)
    }

    state: AdminUserPageState = {
        filters: {
            name: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { data } = this.props
        if (!data || data.content === undefined) {
            // Gettign the users properly.
            this.props.getUsers()
        }
    }

    renderUSers() {
        if (this.props.data.content !== undefined) {
            return this.props.data.content.map((user, index) => {
                return (
                    <tr key={index}>
                        <td>{ user.name }</td>
                    </tr>
                )
            })
        }
    }

    setFilter(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        this.setState({
            filters: {
                name: e.target.value
            }
        })
        // Requesting the users again but the action never get the filters
        this.props.getUsers(this.state.filters)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onChange={ e => this.setFilter(e)  } value={ this.state.filters.name } />
                <Table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.renderUSers()}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ users }: ApplicationState) => {
    return {
        loading: users.loading,
        data: users.data,
        errors: users.errors
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    getUsers: () => dispatch(getUsers())
})

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(AdminUsersPage)
```

I think there is something I dont understund from this workflow with react/redux, also I'm not sure if the rigth way to send the filters is setting them in the state(I guess its not a bad practice thinking I'm going to have multiple filters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    getUsers: () => dispatch(getUsers())
});
```

From the above declaration, `getUser` is registered to dispatch its action without any arguments forwarded to it.

For this reason, invoking `getUsers` with the `filter` doesn't forward `filter` to the action creator.

To register it such that it forwards arguments passed to it, you need to have the function that the component receives accept an argument and forward that to the action creator *e.g.*

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
    getUsers: filter => dispatch(getUsers(filter))
});
```